# Exclude certain rows while calculating the minimum value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table and I need to find the minimum value in that column.

In this case the value is 20.

[image]

However, I need to exclude the last 2 part names and use the rest of the values in the cell to calculate the minimum. In that case the minimum value should be 100.

[image]

Here is the code i have for calculating the minimum:

```js
function getMin() {

 var maximum = 0;

 jQuery(".used").each(function() {
  $used= jQuery(this).val();
  var usedValue = $used.replace(/,/g, "");
  value = parseFloat(usedValue);
  maximum = (value > maximum) ? value : maximum;
 });

 var min = maximum;

 jQuery(".used").each(function() {
  $used = jQuery(this).val();
  var usedValue = $used.replace(/,/g, "");
  value = parseFloat(usedValue);
  min = (value < min) ? value : min;
 });

 jQuery(".minimum").val(min);
}
```

```html
<div><input type="text" class="minimum" name="minimum" id="minimum" value="" size="5" onchange="getMin();" readonly>cycles</div>
```

I couldn't find a way to exclude the last 2 values here. The number of rows can also differ and is not fixed so I need to exclude it based on those 2 string values. Any help is appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there anything about these excluded rows to indicate you want them excluded? Or you just want to hardcode them as "two last rows" (which sounds like a bad idea)?

Comment: @RoboRobok It says "based on those 2 string values"

Comment: @RoboRobok no i don't have anything to exclude them because i need it for rest of the calculation on the page and i kind of need to hard code it only for that particular column.

Comment: I would suggest putting something to HTML code to mark these rows somehow. Hardcoding these names in JS asks for trouble.

Comment: There's no need to have two loops. You can set min and max in the same loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty solution. Loop through the parent object of each row, and ignore the value of used if the label (text) is one of those strings.

I also updated the minimum function to use the math.min on an array of values.

```js
function getMin() {

  let vals = [];

  $(".row").each(function() {
    if ($(this).find("label").html() != "Ignore") {
      $used = $(this).find(".used").val();
      var usedValue = $used.replace(/,/g, "");
      vals.push(parseFloat(usedValue));
    }
  });

  let min = Math.min(...vals);

  $(".minimum").val(min);
}

getMin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <label>Ignore</label>
  <input type="text" class="used" value=41>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <label>Keep</label>
  <input type="text" class="used" value=222>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <label>Keep</label>
  <input type="text" class="used" value=200>
</div>

<div><input type="text" class="minimum" name="minimum" id="minimum" value="" size="5" onchange="" readonly>cycles</div>
```

Comment: Can you click the "Tidy" button in the snippet to format the code?

Comment: @Barmar, I learned something today!! I have completely missed that button every time I have used the snippet editor.

Comment: @imvain2 I tried this but it's not working for me! https://jsfiddle.net/hk6o8qcv/1/

Comment: @ace23 I made a modification and it is working in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ja2n0x6g/

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this: Exclude in your `each()` function every `<tr>` that has a first column that contains any of the 2 strings you want to exclude:

```js
function getMin() {

  var maximum = 0;

  jQuery(".used").each(function() {
    $used = jQuery(this).val();
    var usedValue = $used.replace(/,/g, "");
    value = parseFloat(usedValue);
    maximum = (value > maximum) ? value : maximum;
  });

  var min = maximum;

  jQuery("tr").each(function() {
     var check = jQuery(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
     if (!check.includes("Fan Blade") && !check.includes("Annulus Filler")) 
     {
       $used = jQuery(this).val();
       var usedValue = $used.replace(/,/g, "");
       value = parseFloat(usedValue);
       min = (value < min) ? value : min;
     }
  });

  jQuery(".minimum").val(min);
}
getMin();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><input class="used" value="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Fan Blade (26 off)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td><input class="used" value="50" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Annulus Filler (26 off)</td>
  <td></td>
  <td><input class="used" value="50" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div><input type="text" class="minimum" name="minimum" id="minimum" value="" size="5" onchange="getMin();" readonly>cycles</div>
```

Comment: @ace23 Glad that I was able to help :)

Comment: it looks like like it is skipping those 2 rows but it's not updating for the rest of the column. do i need to add something specific for the rest of the values here?

Comment: @ace23 What do you mean with it's not updating for the rest of the column?

Comment: it's not updating the minimum values based on rest of the columns. if i change other values it's not setting the proper minimum.

Comment: @ace23 the problem is most likely because the code in one loop is restricting based on the td content but the first loop isn't. The best option is merge the loops, add the values to an array and just use `Math.min` on the array to get the Min, using javascript's built in function for calculating min

Comment: @ace23 I've just updated my answer which is working in this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtv76s2x/1/

Comment: @matthias_h since i am using div tags instead of tr tags i replaced it with div but it's not excluding those last 2 rows anymore.

Comment: @ace23 Can you share your actual markup in a Fiddle?

Comment: @matthias_h in your fiddle, it still loops through the ones that should be ignored. In your console.log it still shows `used: 50`

Comment: @imvain2 Thanks for your feedback and good spot, I overlooked that. Trying to work on it.

Comment: @ace23 I've adjusted my answer again, I admit I don't know why the version with :not(:contains()) didn't work but came up with a similar solution.

Comment: @matthias_h i tried that solution. https://jsfiddle.net/yj3atvm7/ here is my project structure. Your solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would mark these different rows in HTML somehow, let's say with `excluded` class. Hardcoding the labels in JavaScript asks for trouble.

Here's an example, using `excluded` class for these two last `<tr>`:

```js
const min = Math.min(...$(':not(.excluded) .used').map(function () {
    return Number($(this).val());
}).get());
```